# Errors when including DES.pyd in python 2.6 solution

Tags: python, des, pycrypto, pyd

I have installed Python 2.7 on my windows 7 x64 system with PyCrypto 2.5 compiled and built in. In my install path of `D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher` I see `DES.pyd`. I have opened it with dependency walker and ensured it had `initDES` as its only export.

What I wanted to do was copy/paste `DES.pyd` out now that it's built and use it in my code. So now I have my project folder `D:\project` containing `test.py` and `DES.pyd`.

`test.py` contains the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("D:\\project\\")
import DES
print 'hi'
```

when running `test.py`, i receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import DES
SystemError: dynamic module not initialized properly</code></pre>
```

The purpose of this exercise is to be able to send `DES.pyd` and `test.py` to my friend without having them require to build and install pycrypto (a PITA). I fully understand my code above does absolutely nothing involving DES, the fact that it cannot import it is my main curiosity. Real code using DES will follow.

Also, if I import `DES.pyd` directly from the python path like `from Crypto.Cipher import DES` works just fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source code at https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/src/block_template.c#L801. The module name is hard coded to `Crypto.Cipher._DES`. Initialization will fail if `_DES.pyd` is not in the `Crypto.Cipher` package directory.